# C++ vector iterators vs. pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator

There are so many alternative ways of addressing elements of a vector.

I could use a pointer like so:

```
vector<int> v = {10, 11, 12};
int *p = &v[0];
cout << *p;    //Outputs "10"
```

I could use a pointer this way too:

```
vector<int> v = {10, 11, 12};
vector<int>::pointer p = v.data();
cout << *p;    //Outputs "10"
```

I could also use the iterator type:

```
vector<int> v = {10, 11, 12};
vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin();
cout << *i;    //Outputs "10"
```

Are there any significant differences that I'm missing here?

Comment: _"addressing elements of a vector"_, Why not you use the simplest, `v[0]`.

Comment: unless you need to I would recommend the usual way of addressing vector elements

Comment: @BSH safety. what if the vector is empty?  you also have `vector::front`

Comment: @BSH That doesn't give you an iterator.

Comment: don't forget `back`, `front`, and `at`

Comment: The middle one cannot be checked by a checked-implementation for correctness (aka is there any element), the other two can. All release-mode implementations are unchecked.

Comment: @Deduplicator: the default Release configuration in VC++ does NOT drop to unchecked mode…

Comment: @MFH: Iterators have been [unchecked in Release mode since VS2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Iterators involve more overhead, but they can be used for stuff like a custom compare function for STL functions like std::sort, where the STL functions manipulate the iterators passed to them. Then again, using a lambda function that includes the vector name along with pointers also solves the issue if your compiler supports lambda functions.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: You're definitely right there, SCL and IDL are set to 0 and one can make the argument that "non-SCL iterator" =(semantically)= pointer, but as Deduplicator claimed that »vector<int>::iterator and int* are quite likely to be identical in release configuration« I just had to leave a note that that won't EVER happen in (modern, currently available) versions of VC++…

Comment: @rcgldr a conforming implementation may implement `std::vector<T>::iterator` as an alias to `T *`. pointers satisfy the Iterator concept

Answer (score 14):

As far as being able to perform the task at hand, they all work equally well. After all, they all provide an object which meets the requirements of an iterator and you are using them to point at the same element of the `vector`. **However**, I would pick the `vector<int>::iterator` option because the type is more expressive about how we intend to use it.

The raw pointer type, `int*`, tells you very little about what `p` is, except that it stores the address of an `int`. If you think about `p` in isolation, its type doesn't tell you very much about how you can use it. The `vector<int>::pointer` option has the same issue - it just expresses the type of the objects it points at as being the element type of a vector. There's no reason it actually needs to point into a `vector`.

On the other hand `vector<int>::iterator` tells you everything you need to know. It explicitly states that the object is an iterator and that iterator is used to point at elements in a `vector<int>`.

This also has the benefit of being more easily maintainable if you ever happen to change the container type. If you changed to a `std::list`, for example, the pointer type just wouldn't work any more because the elements are not stored as a contiguous array. The `iterator` type of a container always provides you with a type you can use to iterate over its elements.

---

When we have Concepts, I'd expect the best practise to be something like:

```
ForwardIteratorOf<int> it = std::begin(v);
```

where `ForwardIteratorOf<int>` (which I am imagining exists) is changed to whatever concept best describes your intentions for `it`. If the type of the elements doesn't matter, then just `ForwardIterator` (or `BidirectionalIterator`, `RandomAccessIterator`, or whatever).

Comment: Just one small comment: I expect `auto` will still be preferred. Also, you might want to add that `vector<int>::iterator` and `int*` are quite likely to be identical in release configurations.

Comment: @Deduplicator: only they are NEVER in VC++

Comment: std::list doesn't have random access iterators, so changing from std::vector to std::list could present issues even if using iterators.

Comment: @MFH `vector<int>::iterator` might not be declared as an alias for `int*`, but the expectation is the object code is the same (in release mode)

Answer (score 4):

If you add the check:

```
if ( !v.empty() )
```

Then, all the example you've shown are equally valid.

If you are about to iterate over the elements of the `vector`, I would go with:

```
vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin();
```

It's easier to check whether the iterator has reached the end of the vector with an iterator than with the other forms.

```
if ( i != v.end() )
{
   // Do stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All these ways have their advantages, but at the core they are very similar. Some of them don't work though (they cause so-called "undefined behaviour") when the vector is empty.

Comment: So, what are the respective advantages? Aside: Any reason for the scare-quotes on UB?

Comment: Not scare quotes, just quotes, to make clear that this is not just two words combined but a single term. Else I could just as well have written UB and left it to the reader to figure out what this means.

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](https://www.en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator):

> A pointer to an element of an array satisfies all requirements of LegacyContiguousIterator

which is the most powerful iterator as it encompasses all other iterators functionality.  So they can be one and the same, an iterator is just a means of making our code clear, consice and  portable.

For example we could have some container "C"...

```
//template <typename T, int N> class C { //for static allocation
template <typename T> class C {
    //T _data[N]; //for static allocation
    T* _data; //need to dynamically allocate _data
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
}
```

where `C<int>::iterator` would be an `int*` and there would be no difference.

Maybe we don't want/need the full power of a *LegacyContiguousIterator* so we could redefine `C<int>::iterator`
as another class that follows the outline for say *LegacyForwardIterator*. This new iterator class may redefine `operator*`. In this case it is implementation dependant and an `int*` may cause undefined behaviour when trying to access the elements.

This is why iterators should be preferred but in most cases they are going to be the same thing.

In both cases  our container " C" will work just like other STL containers so long as we define all the other necessary member functions and typedefs.