# Why most of C++ STL library functions use iterator as parameter?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I not getting a clear difference between pointers and iterators.
Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ vector iterators vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393431/c-vector-iterators-vs-pointers)

Comment: To make matters worse, pointers can be used as iterators; And when dereferencing an iterator you can use the pointer-to operator to get a pointer (for an iterator `it` then `&*it` will get a pointer to the object that the iterator references).

Comment: Are the specific Versions of C++ standard relevant to the question? If yes, you should specify how they impact the answer you want and if not, you could remove the tags.

Comment: Literally ALL of the `STL` functions (algorithms) use *iterators*, they are part of its core design and its brilliance. They provide a generalization that decouples algorithms from the data they work on.

Comment: Whereas `std::vector::iterator` might be a pointer, it cannot be for `std::list::iterator`, `std::map::iterator`, ...

Comment: Iterators look like pointers only if what you ever do is iterate vectors in the forward direction. A `std::list::iterator` is kind of a pointer but normal pointer `++` and `--` do not work with it. A `std::reverse_iterator` is kind of a pointer but with `++` and `--` reversed. A `std::back_inserter` is not like a pointer at all. A `std::istream_iterator` is not like a pointer at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I not getting a clear difference between pointers and iterators.

Iterator is a concept of a type whose instance that can point to an object, and that can be incremented to point to the next sibling element.

A pair of iterators pointing to the same container represent a range of objects within the container.

Pointers can point to an object and if the pointed object is an element of an array, then the pointer can be incremented to point to the next element of the array. Pointers are an example of an iterator for array types. There are other iterator types besides pointers, for other container types.

> Why most of C++ STL library functions use iterator as parameter?

Those functions are implementations of algorithms that operate on sequences of objects, and they remain fundamentally the same regardless of the data structure that hold the objects.

If you have an array of objects, you can use the function by passing a pair of pointers into a range of objects within the array, and if you have another container, then you can use a pair of iterators pointing to elements of that container.

Being able to call the function with any (restrictions apply) iterator, allows us to use those functions with any container.

Answer (score 2):

Because C++ iterators need not to be pointers, and taking iterators as argument enables C++ users to define their own iterators with being able to use STL algorithms.

As an example, here is my custom iterator for my toy-project B-Tree:
(https://github.com/frozenca/CLRS/blob/main/18/18_B_tree.cpp#L145)

```
template <bool Const>
    struct BTreeIterator {
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = std::conditional_t<Const, const T*, T*>;
        using reference = std::conditional_t<Const, const T&, T&>;
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;

        Node* node = nullptr;
        std::size_t index;

        void Increment() {
            if (index == node->key.size()) {
                return;
            }
            if (node->child.empty()) {
                ++index;
                while (node->parent && index == node->key.size()) {
                    index = node->index;
                    node = node->parent;
                }
            } else {
                node = node->child[index + 1]->LeftmostLeaf();
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        void Decrement() {
            if (!node->leaf) {
                node = node->child[index]->RightmostLeaf();
                index = node->key.size() - 1;
            } else {
                if (index > 0) {
                    --index;
                } else {
                    while (node->parent && node->index == 0) {
                        node = node->parent;
                    }
                    if (node->index > 0) {
                        index = node->index - 1;
                        node = node->parent;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        BTreeIterator() = default;

        BTreeIterator(Node* node, std::size_t i) : node {node}, index {i} {
            assert(node && i <= node->key.size());
        }

        reference operator*() const {
            return node->key[index];
        }

        pointer operator->() const {
            return node->key.begin() + index;
        }

        BTreeIterator& operator++() {
            Increment();
            return *this;
        }

        BTreeIterator operator++(int) {
            BTreeIterator temp = *this;
            Increment();
            return temp;
        }

        BTreeIterator& operator--() {
            Decrement();
            return *this;
        }

        BTreeIterator operator--(int) {
            BTreeIterator temp = *this;
            Decrement();
            return temp;
        }

    };


// ...

using iterator = BTreeIterator<false>;
using const_iterator = BTreeIterator<true>;
using reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<iterator>;
using const_reverse_iterator = std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>;
```

Since I provided `iterator_category`, `difference_type`, `value_type`, `pointer`, `reference`, the class `BTreeIterator` can be used for applying range-for loop, `std::copy`, `std::accumulate`, etc, for my B-Tree.

Answer (score 0):

The ["STL" aka standard template library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) was largely proposed by [Alexander Stephanov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Stepanov) in the '80-'90. The [iterator (design) pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) was still quite new and popular at the time.

You must imagine that computers weren't very strong at the time, so performance was an issue. Compile times were also very long. Before that memory addressing was done with pointer arithmetic. But that's both not safe (easy to make a mistake) and limited, as not all objects (i.e. bits in a `vector<bool>`) can be accessed using pointers. Iterators form an abstraction layer. However, at the time people were already complaining about this very small layer, because it would increase the already long compiler times. So a more complex solution was not even feasible.

The nice thing of the STL is that the algorithms compose. (Together they intentionally form the parts of a stable sort.)

Iterators also give some control, e.g.

```cpp
std::copy(vec.rbegin()+1, vec.rend()-1, std::back_inserter(other));
```

copes the elements from `vec`, except the first and the last, in reverse order while inserting them at the back of `other`.